# How to get current (selected) tool from toolbars (map navigration tools & object selection panel) and change it in code

Tags: pyqgis

[image: toolbars]

I'm developing a plugin for QGIS, and for further implementation there should be logic that automatically switches current tool to 'select objects', and, after selection, returns to the previous tool.

Comment: Have you tried any coding so far?